# Нет соединения с БД java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> Только начал изучение Бд,столкнулся с проблемой : могу подключиться к
> БД.В чем ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Main.java

```
    package com.devcolibri.datavase;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {
    private static String driver   = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private final static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    private final static String DBNAME= "gregs_list";
    private final static String USERNAME ="root";
    private final static String PASSWORD ="root";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con ;

        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL+DBNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
            if (conn != null)
                System.out.println ("Приложение подключилось к БД !");
            else
                System.out.println ("Приложение НЕ подключилось к БД ?");

            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.devcolibri</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.devcolibri.databaseexam</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <dependencies><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <version>8.0.11</version>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Смотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gregs_list?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "root");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }
}
```

> Рабочий вариант.